# Nulls and ERDs. Where does the Null go?

Tags: sql-server, database, null, relational-database, diagram

I am confused with this simple relationship.

What I am trying to say here is that each member can have **only** one row in Marketing Target, however, the Foreign Key - MemberID - must be set to Null as I am saving the data after deleting the Member Details.

Please not that I am not asking about the codes, but about where I should put the Null in the diagram.

Is it correct where I have or should it go next to Marketing?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: "the Foreign Key - MemberID - must be set to Null as I am saving the data after deleting the Member Details." doesn't make any sense. If you can have a record in `MarketingTarget` without a corresponding (same `MemberID`) record in `MemberDetails`, then you don't have a Foreign Key relationship. Please explain what it means for there to be a record in `MarketingTarget`.

Comment: It means when I delete the data from Member Details, the FK is set to Null and the Marketing Target records are not deleted. I need to keep this records after I have deleted the Member Details. This is a requirement. The codes I wrote are working just fine, but I am confused on where to add the NULL in the ERD.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not commets. PS You have a textbook/reference. Follow it, don't ask us to rewrite it. Also, what did your other research show? [ask] [help] PS Put text as text in your post, here all the content of the image, and give a legend with an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your foreign keys wrong way round.

Instead of `MarketingTarget.MemberID` you should have `MemberDetails.MTid` linking to `MarketingTarget' table.

As a general rule you always add a foreign key to the "many" or 0 side of the relationship.